# Convert date and time which is in character to numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2

My file time and date row is in character format and when I try to make a graph then it shows all the date and time in x axis so we cant read the x axis at all.

```
ggplot(Mk, aes(Timestamp, Value, group=Label, color=Label)) +geom_line()
```

[image: plot]

I tried different things which I found here but always got some error.

```
POSIX
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(data=Mk,Timestamp, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")))

as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Timestamp))

strptime
strptime(df$Timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: Don't link to Dropbox, use `dput()` instead (or `dput(head())` if it is too long).

Comment: can you please send one Timestamp of your MK dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove seconds from time formatting

```
 mk <- read.csv("mk.csv")


 head(mk)
  Label Value      Timestamp
1    W5 0.333 6/24/2017 0:00
2    W5 0.333 6/24/2017 0:30
3    W5 0.334 6/24/2017 1:00
4    W5 0.334 6/24/2017 1:30
5    W5 0.334 6/24/2017 2:00
6    W5 0.334 6/24/2017 2:30

 mk$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(mk$Timestamp,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

 head(mk)
  Label Value           Timestamp
1    W5 0.333 2017-06-24 00:00:00
2    W5 0.333 2017-06-24 00:30:00
3    W5 0.334 2017-06-24 01:00:00
4    W5 0.334 2017-06-24 01:30:00
5    W5 0.334 2017-06-24 02:00:00
6    W5 0.334 2017-06-24 02:30:00
```

Then simply plot

```
ggplot(mk, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Value, colour=Label)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir!